# How to tackle this duplicate content issue?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, duplicate-content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

I've a new website coming up with 1000's of page which will contain some city codes. I'd also like to place city info copied from Wikipedia(as per Creative Commons License).
Now the focus of the pages will be city codes. Wikipedia content will be there only to improve page appearance.

However it can be slapped duplicate content penalty so I should use rel=canonical. 
But the main content/focus of site is some city codes and not Wikipedia info per se. Rel=canonical will give impression that whole part of page is duplicated lowering the page seo worth.
**What should I do to tackle this duplicate content issue?**

Comment: Will different pages on your site contain the same content, or are you worried about content that appears on your site and wikipedia?

Comment: No, each page will list only one city code. For each city there'll be only single page. So the Wikipedia info about the city will be unique from other pages.

Comment: The rel=canonical tag is for saying "of these pages that look like duplicates on my site, this is the canonical one". That isn't relevant in this case. So the answer you've been given is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the Wikipedia-content portion of each page in something that can't be indexed or won't be indexed. There are a lot of ways to do this: frames, javascripts, etc. It's weird for me to advise someone to do that, but it seems like what you want in this situation.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the main objective of the Wikipedia content-- to increase the page bulk ( ie no. of words). Ideally 900 words is ok as per SEO. Since the user will be looking only for a city code -- that'll do in a line, I want the Wikipedia page to be indexed by Search Engines and my website page also be rewarded "some" SEO points. I've done the same in my one previous site: http://www.downloadformsindia.com/Tripura/tripura-application-form-for-permanent-registration-as-small-scale-industries-industries-commerce.html  (check the pdf text in the bottom of the page).